# Does the Expectimax AI still work as expected if not all branched are explored to the same depth?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minimax

I am making an expectimax AI, and the branching factor of this game is unpredictable, ranging from 6 - 20. I'm currently exploring the game tree for 1 second every turn, then making sure the whole game tree is explored to the same depth, but occasionally this results in a very large slowdown, if branching factor for a particular turn jumps up radically. Is if OK if I cut off exploration when parts of the game tree are not explored as deeply? Will this affect the mathematical properties of expectimax at all?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: I'm pretty sure **you lose the mathematical guarantees**, but the extent to which this affects your program's performance will probably depend on the game and your board evaluation function.

Here's an abstract scenario to give you some intuition for where having different branch lengths might create the most problems: say that, for player one, the best move is something that takes a few turns to set up. Let's say this set up is not something that your board evaluation function can pick up on. In this case, regardless of what player 2 does in the mean time, there will be a point a few moves in the future where the score of the board will swing in the direction that favors player 1. If one branch gets far enough to see that move and another doesn't, it will look like the first is a worse option for player 2, despite the fact that the same thing will happen on the other branch. If the move that player 2 made in the first branch was actually better than the move it made in the second branch, **this would lead to a suboptimal choice**.

On the other hand, a perfect board evaluator would make this impossible (it would recognize player 1 setting up their move). There are also games in which setting up moves in advance like this is not possible. But the existence of this case is a red flag.

**Fundamentally, branches that didn't get evaluated as far have greater uncertainty in their estimations of how good a move is. This will sometimes result in them being chosen when they shouldn't be and other times it will result in them not being chosen when they should be.** As a result, I would strongly suspect that you lose mathematical guarantees by doing this. That said, the practical impact of this problem on performance may or may not be substantial.

There might be some way around this if you incorporate the current turn number into the board evaluation function and adjust for it accordingly. Minimally, that would allow you to explicitly account for the added uncertainty in shorter branches.